# updateProgress(double,double) has protected access in Task

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have implemented my own `javafx.concurrent.Task`, and I want to call its `updateProgress` method outside its class declaration but error says: **updateProgress(double,double) has protected access in Task**

**Example:**

```
downloadTask.updateProgress(index,size);
```

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Why would you need this? The fact that it's protected means the designers thought it should only be accessed from within the task, which makes sense. Wanting to call it from outside means you may be doing something wrong. Anyway, you can always increase the [visibility of the method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780779/why-java-allows-increasing-the-visibility-of-protected-methods-in-child-class).

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html

Code snippet from javadoc:

```
 public class IteratingTask extends Task<Integer> {
         private final int totalIterations;

         public IteratingTask(int totalIterations) {
             this.totalIterations = totalIterations;
         }

         @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
             int iterations = 0;
             for (iterations = 0; iterations < totalIterations; iterations++) {
                 if (isCancelled()) {
                     updateMessage("Cancelled");
                     break;
                 }
                 updateMessage("Iteration " + iterations);
                 updateProgress(iterations, totalIterations);
             }
             return iterations;
         }
     }
```